# WebSocket Streaming dual videos

Tags: node.js, video, websocket, video-streaming

Wanted to clear a few questions about websocket.

- Is it possible to stream videos from server to client and client to server at the same time...something like video calling?
- Can the server stream two videos to a single client at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question, yes you can. There are already wrappers that simplify that task such as [BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/).

As per your second question, it would require a little extra configuration. Once a bidirectional link between client and server is established, the client will treat every incoming message as part of the same stream. Separating or multiplexing two videos in the same stream would have to carry another mark to help the client separate it.

It would be a better idea to open a new connection (with the same server) to stream a second video.

Comment: Is it possible to create more than one connections between the client and server?

Comment: And regarding streaming.....I am not saying about only streaming from server to client...I m asking for both s2c n c2s at the same time

Comment: Yes, both browser and server can use the stream method to deliver messages or the binary content of a file/stream

Comment: At the same time? Like suppose video calling?

Comment: Yes, but it would make no sense to videocall a server. The server should only relay inbound and outbound messages between two clients. Or N clients if it's a multi video chat.

Comment: No it's not a video call in that true sense. And I m just looking to have a relay server in node.js.